# pyproj returning inf for UTM

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, utm, pyproj

I am gettin x = [inf inf inf.....] and y = [inf inf inf...]. Has anyone encountered this error before? I am attempting to convert lon and lat into x y values. I have the following code but I cannot figure out what is incorrect. This is San Diego data set.

```
import scipy.io;
from pyproj import Proj;

canyon = scipy.io.loadmat('INIT.MAT');
topo = canyon.get('siocanyon');

lat = tuple(topo[:, 0])
lon = tuple(topo[:, 1])
z = topo[:, 2]

myProj = Proj(proj='utm', zone=11, ellps='WGS84', preserve_units=False)
y, x = myProj(lon, lat)
```

Comment: Can you link website where I can download the dataset and read about it? Hard to test without it.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1V9b-39NNh3wS52-ol0DjzA8RWsM7jfPP

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the code with a sample position from San Diego:

```
from pyproj import Proj

lat = 32.715687
lon = -117.161380
#z = 100

myProj = Proj(proj='utm', zone=11, ellps='WGS84', preserve_units=False)
x, y = myProj(lon, lat)
print(x, y)
```

gives

```
484876.3791751535 3619780.206742558
```

You can test your results using an [online converter](https://tool-online.com/en/coordinate-converter.php).

Comment: Did you try the snippet above? One possible explanation for your error could be if you swapped lat with lon when reading.